# How to get the negative position value in Group?

Tags: apache-flex

The dashed rectangle is the parent group and inside, there is a label. Its x is negative.

Now, what I want to do is relocation the outside group to the contents' top-left point and meanwhile the contents' move back to the outside group's (0,0) point. The result looks like everything keeps the same position as before.but in fact, both inside content and outside group is moved.

It is easy to realize in flash, however, in flex i got trouble.

The function "getRect" returns wrong values.it's never return the correct position the inside content is.(like the thumb shows,the position should be like [-70,50])

[image]

Comment: try innercontent.x and y to get the current position

Comment: Thanks Zeus,how about if there is many children,not just one?

Answer (score 0):

(Feel free to correct me because I'm not sure what you want to accomplish here)

If your Label (let's say it is called myLabel) is correctly located directly inside of your Group, simply calling myLabel.x will return the X-coordinate of the label compared to its parent (which is your Group here, so you should get -70).

Then if you want to move the label so it fits into your Group viewport, you have two solutions:

- Either you manually set myLabel.x = 0 and myLabel.y = 0. In this case the label will actually be moved at the Group origin.
- Either you retrieve the matrix of your label component to call its .translate(dx, dy) function. Using the matrix functions will modify the way your Label is displayed, but its position will remain unchanged (More information about that [on this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#translate%28%29)).

**Short answer**: If you don't care about keeping the original position of your label, just set myLabel.x = 0 and myLabel.y = 0 and it should be moved correctly.

Comment: thanks Cédric,but if there is not only one label in the group,how can i got the all content's top-left point? if i can't use getRect directly,maybe i have to traverse all children to find out all content's left-top point and size